# Generating random questions from a text file - C#

Tags: c#, string, random

I want to provide the user with a selection of questions but I want them to be random, having a quiz game with the same questions isn't exactly fun.

My idea was to store a large collection of questions and there appropiate answers in a text file:

```
What colour is an Strawberry|Red
How many corners are there on a Triangle|Three
```

This means that I could simply select a line at random, read the question and answer from the line and store them in a collection to be used in the game.

I've come up with some pseudo code with an approach I think would be useful and am looking for some input as to how it could be improved:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int line;
string question,answer;

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   line = rand.Next();
   //Read question at given line number to string
   //Read answer at given line number to string
   //Copy question and answer to collection
}
```

In terms of implementing the idea I'm unsure as to how I can specify a line number to read from as well as how to split the entire line and read both parts separately. Unless there's a better way my thoughts are manually entering a line number in the text file followed by a "|" so each line looks like this:

```
1|What colour is an Strawberry|Red
2|How many corners are there on a Triangle|Three
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I suggest never using plain text files for structured data, how simple the data structure may be at first. An XML file should serve you much better in the long run.

Comment: `3|What is this character '|' used for?|Pipe commands.`

Comment: @GCATNM or an in process database like CompactSQL. This gives you an easy way to only fetch only those rows you want to display to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not read the entire file into an array or a list using [ReadLine](http://dotnetperls.com/readline) and then refer to a random index within the bounds of the array to pull the question/answer string from, rather than reading from the text file when you want a question.

As for parsing it, just use [Split](http://dotnetperls.com/string-split) to split it at the `|` delineator (and make sure that no questions have a `|` in the question for some reason). This would also let you store some wrong answers with the question (just say that the first one is always right, then when you output it you can randomize the order).

Comment: Great idea! Also means I can expand upon it if I add new items to a line.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to display any questions twice, right?

```
Random random = new Random();
var q = File.ReadAllLines("questions.txt")
    .OrderBy(x=>random.Next())
    .Take(20)
    .Select(x=>x.Split('|'))
    .Select(x=>new QuestionAndAnswer(){Question=x[0],Answer=x[1]});
```

Comment: This is good, assuming the file isn't huge, which is probably the case.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the above code works? I have a feeling I understand it but I just want to be sure.

Comment: This code is cute, but for every second of serious mental labor used to produce it you'll need at least a second to understand it each time you try to read it. And maybe more.

Comment: @Dialecticus that's what most people say when they're not used to LINQ. Then you get used to what the operators are, and then 3 lines of LINQ becomes much more readable than 3 lines of C#, let alone the 30 lines of equivalent C#.

Comment: I agree, although I do think they tend to be more readable when you write them as a linq query